# How to store an image in a variable in Java? (Android Development)

Tags: java, android

I've searched around Google and Bing for a while, but so far have only found legit answers pertaining to JavaScript and similar web scripting languages.  Hoping one of you fine folks could provide me some insight on the best way to go about this.

Basically I'm developing a card-game for Android, and I'm storing my individual cards in an ArrayList of the class Card.  Card, so far, has three priv variables: Rank, Suit and Image.  Rank and suit are obvious, but I'm stumped as for a way to store the image for the card in the class.  Should I store a string that is the directory for the image in res/mdpi, or should I actually store it as a bitmap (if that's even possible...).

Basically  I want to be able to, when dealing the cards in later-created classes, to use a method that will randomly select a card, make sure it hasn't been dealt yet, then deal the card.  I'm guessing I'll draw it to the screen by calling something like "Card.drawCard" where "drawCard" is a method of "Card" I will create to paint the card...  Probably end up doing it a completely different way, but I'll learn-as-I-go.

So... How do I store the image in a variable?

Answer (score 2):

Use [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) to decode an image to bitmap and store it in memory. like:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/image.jpg");
```

then you can use [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) to draw bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the Bitmap class.

```
    Bitmap b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.bitmap);//R.drawable.bitmap is the bitmap in your drawable folder.
    ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
```

and use

```
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.bitmap);
```

or

```
    iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

The above method is a very simple way of displaying graphics. 
For more advanced graphics, 
extend some View class and make your custom graphics.

Comment: Might be usingthis wrong, but I'm doing it this way:deck.add(new Card("Ace","Spade", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.as))); and im getting an errorsaying getResources() isnt a method of class Deck (class holding the ArrayList of cards.  Do i have to imprt something?

Comment: You have to use it in a Context object.

Answer (score 1):

use the Bitmap to store image in bitmap . 
i.e when you store name , then u use string. if you wanna to store image then use bitmap.

```
public BitMap image;
```